# Explode string without using a separator

Tags: php, string

I have a program that gererates data and with that data it includes the date in the format

```
20111212
```

(That would be todays date [12-12-2011] ). Is there a way to explode that into the four segments like

```
2011
12
12
```

so I can put a `-` between those numbers.
My end aim is to have the date in the form DD-MMY-YYY.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is your format allway gonna be YYYYMMDD?

Comment: Will it always be in YYYYMMDD or YYYYDDMM format?

Comment: use substr() instead of explode()

Comment: It will be changed to DD-MMY-YYY but first I want to explode it into 3 sections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your format alway YYYYMMDD then first take 4 digits as year, then take 2 digits as month and last take 2 digits as date. see substring function for php in google.

Answer (score 8):

There is no need to "explode" the string. You can use the function [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) for this. It will *"[p]arse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp"*. Then you can pass this timestamp to the function `date()` to format the date any way you want to.

```
$date = '20111212';
$timestamp = strtotime($date);

echo date('d-m-Y', $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = preg_replace('(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})', '$1-$2-$3', $date);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php